# Верстка с использованием VW, отличие от PX, %, и других величин

Tags: html, css, adaptive-design

Я начинающий front-end разработчик и недавно мне повезло найти работу на фрилансе.

Всё было бы хорошо, но у заказчика есть 1 требование, к которому я не был готов - верстать всё на `vw`.

Я никогда исключительно на `vw` не верстал и поэтому хотелось бы узнать о подводных камнях и особенностях такой верстки, в чём её преимущество и самое главное, как работать со шрифтами, ибо шрифты на `vw` будет очень маленькими на на маленьких экранах?

Answer (score 5):

Работа с `VW` отличаеться от `%` тем что в первом случае Вы отталкиваетесь от размеров viewport'a, а во втором от размеров ближайшего родительского элемента.

VW:

```
// ширина viewport'a равна 300px 

html {
   width: 100vw; // 300px
}

body {
   width: 50vw; // 150px
}

body div {
   width: 50vw; // 150px
}
```

%:

```
// ширина viewport'a равна 300px 

html {
   width: 100%; // 300px
}

body {
   width: 50%; // 150px
}

body div {
   width: 50%; // 75px
}
```

Я не встречал ситуации когда кто то использует VW для задания размеров шрифта, при работе с ними обычно используются относительные величины, такие как REM и EM.

REM равен размеру шрифта, заданного для `html` и/или `body`:

```
html {
   font-size: 16px;
}

body {
   font-size: inherit;
}

div {
   font-size: 1rem; // 16px
}

span {
   font-size: 2rem; // 32px
}
```

EM рассчитывается относительно размера шрифта родительского элемента:

```
div {
   font-size: 16px; // 16px
}

div span {
   font-size: 0.5em; // 8px
}
```

[Справка по CSS Размерам](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Comment: Em это вроде от ширины буквы M? Тоесть может гулять если шрифт не тот

Comment: Это не совсем то, что я хотел узнать, но всё равно спасибо. Например я хотел узнать, что на экранах меньше 900(примерно) верстка на vw начинает сильно ехать и там, либо переходить на %, px, rem, либо всё выправлять в медиа, хотя и так и так придётся править. Это вот я понял, сверстав 1 страницу.